# Adding reference entity to parse an XML file in JAVA

Tags: java, xml

I am reading an XML file in JAVA like this:

```
String filepath = xmlFile;
File workFile = new File(filepath);
File fragmentDir = workFile.getParentFile();
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filepath);
```

And in this xml file there is references like &testRef;

I have an other file where I declared all the entities like this:

```
<!ENTITY testRef 'hello"'>
```

The simple solution is to add directly these references in the xml file or add an !ENTITY system "file.ref" but I can't.
Is there a solution where I can tell to my DocumentBuilderFactory  : use this file to read the references?

Edit: I've tried this:

```
docBuilder.setEntityResolver(new EntityResolver() {
            public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId) throws SAXException,IOException {
                System.out.println("Resolving");
                return new InputSource("file.ref");
            }
        });
```

But I keep getting "The entity "testRef" was referenced, but not declared...", the text "Resolving" is not even print. It seems that the document builder doesn't take into account the new resolver.

What am I missing?

Comment: If you need the entities in the file then to be valid XML the ENTITY definition must be in the file, so that is the only way for XML tools to read it. I would ask why you can't add the entities and tell the author of the files they are invalid and they need to fix them.

Comment: In fact these XML files are included in other XML files where the Entity definition is correctly set. But I can't get these files or edit the files I have.

Comment: So you need the whole set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DocumentBuilder`'s `setEntityResolver` method.

```
class Resolver implements EntityResolver {

  public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId) {
  if (systemId.equals("THE_SYSTEM_ID_THAT_YOU_ARE_USING")) {
     System.out.println("Resolving Entity...");
     return new InputSource("YOUR_REFERENCES_XML");
  } else {
     // use the default behaviour
     return null;
  }
  }
}
```

and then

```
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Resolver res = new Resolver();
builder.setEntityResolver(res);
Document doc = builder.parse("YOUR XML FILE");
```

EDIT:

After looking a deeper look at EntityResolver, I see that the entity resolver is ignored if the XML file doesn't declare the Entity Refernce file (which is the problem that you have at hand). 
However you can adapt below trick to make it work:

```
static String template =
           "<!DOCTYPE x [ "
         + "<!ENTITY  % entities SYSTEM \"{0}\"> "
         + "<!ENTITY file SYSTEM \"{1}\" >" + "%entities;" + "]>"
         + "<x>&file;</x>";

 private static String createFromTemplate(File entityFile, File xmlFile) {
     return MessageFormat.format(template, entityFile.getAbsolutePath(),
             xmlFile.getAbsolutePath());
 }

 private static File entityFile = new File(<ENTITYFILE>);

 public Document parse(File f) throws JDOMException, IOException {
     String xml = createFromTemplate(entityFile, f);
     SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
     Document doc = builder.build(new StringReader(xml));
     Element e = (Element) doc.getRootElement().getChildren().get(0);
     e.detach();
     Document doc2 = new Document(e);
     return doc2;
 }
```

The ENTITYFILE is the file where the Entity References are declared.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for you answer but I'm not sure what should I use insted of "YOUR_REFERENCES_XML" ?

Comment: YOUR_REFERENCES_XML is the path to the file where you have your Entities declared ("file.ref", as mentioned in your example).

Comment: Oh ok I tough it was "THE_SYSTEM_ID_THAT_YOU_ARE_USING", what is this then :)

Comment: "THE_SYSTEM_ID_THAT_YOU_ARE_USING" can be used if you have many Entity References files and you want to use appropriate file based on the entity references defined in your XML file.
Since you don't have any such declaration, you can ignore the if-else part of the resolveEntity method and simply do `return new InputSource("YOUR_REFERENCES_XML")'`

Comment: @Mublin Ive done this docBuilder.setEntityResolver(new EntityResolver() {
             public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId) throws SAXException,IOException {
              System.out.println("Resolving");
              return new InputSource("file.ref");
             }
         }); but when the parser find an entity he crash and dont even write "Resolving". Am I missing something ?

Comment: @Rems Update your question with whatever you tried and the exception that you got before the parser "crashed"

Comment: Genius trick ! That worked perfectly. Thanks you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        System.out.println("Start Process");
        File xmlFile = new File("/Users/cgonzalez/Desktop/test.xml");
        SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
        Document document = new Document();
        document = builder.build(xmlFile);

        HashMap piMap = new HashMap(2);
        piMap.put("type", "text/xsl");
        piMap.put("href", "http://localhost:8080/achs-expdf-web/app/resource/xslt/plantilla.xsl");
        ProcessingInstruction pi = new ProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", piMap);

        document.getContent().add(0, pi);

        // new XMLOutputter().output(doc, System.out);
        XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();

        // display nice nice
        xmlOutput.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());
        xmlOutput.output(document, new FileWriter("/Users/cgonzalez/Desktop/test.xml"));
        System.out.println("end Process");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: use JDOM <dependency>
   <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
   <artifactId>jdom2</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.6</version>
  </dependency>